# Separating Data Source to another class in Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, swift, datasource

I'm trying to keep my view controllers clean as described in this article [objc.io Issue #1 Lighter View Controllers](http://www.objc.io/issue-1/lighter-view-controllers.html). I tested this method in Objective-C and it works fine. I have a separate class which implements `UITableViewDataSource` methods.

```
#import "TableDataSource.h"

@interface TableDataSource()

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *items;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *cellIdentifier;

@end

@implementation TableDataSource

- (id)initWithItems:(NSArray *)items cellIdentifier:(NSString *)cellIdentifier {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.items = items;
        self.cellIdentifier = cellIdentifier;
    }
    return self;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return self.items.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:self.cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.textLabel.text = self.items[indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}

@end
```

From the tableview controller, all I have to do is instantiate a instance of this class and set it as the tableview's data source and it works perfectly.

```
self.dataSource = [[TableDataSource alloc] initWithItems:@[@"One", @"Two", @"Three"] cellIdentifier:@"Cell"];
self.tableView.dataSource = self.dataSource;
```

Now I'm trying to do the same in Swift. First here's my code. Its pretty much of a translation of the Objective-C code above.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

public class TableDataSource: NSObject, UITableViewDataSource {

    var items: [AnyObject]
    var cellIdentifier: String

    init(items: [AnyObject]!, cellIdentifier: String!) {
        self.items = items
        self.cellIdentifier = cellIdentifier

        super.init()
    }

    public func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return items.count
    }

    public func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

        cell.textLabel?.text = items[indexPath.row] as? String

        return cell
    }

}
```

And I call it like this.

```
let dataSource = TableDataSource(items: ["One", "Two", "Three"], cellIdentifier: "Cell")
tableView.dataSource = dataSource
```

But the app crashes with the following error.

**-[NSConcreteNotification tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance**

I checked the `init` method of `TableDataSource` and the items and the cell identifier gets passed fine. I had to declare the `UITableViewDataSource` methods `public` and remove the `override` keyword otherwise it would give compile time errors.

I'm clueless on what's going wrong here. Can anyone please help me out?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you show the stack trace at the point of crashing?

Comment: It looks like your data source isn't being retained. Where are you storing the reference?

Comment: @jlehr That was indeed the problem. I _wasn't_ storing it! I made a property `var dataSource: TableDataSource!` and assigned it to the `dataSource` property of the tableview and it works now :) Thank you.

Comment: This happens because the `delegate` and `dataSource` properties of `UITableView` (and other views/controls) are declared as `unowned` in Swift, so you need your own reference to the delegate/data source (if it isn't the view controller itself).

Comment: @NateCook I did see the `unowned` thing when I checked the type of the `dataSource` property but had no idea what it was. Thank you for clearing that up.

Comment: How do you update datasource with new items. is there any method to update the table list?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Create a property for data source and use it with your tableview.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

  @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
  var dataSource:TableDataSource!

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    dataSource = TableDataSource(items: ["One", "Two", "Three"], cellIdentifier: "Cell")

   tableView.dataSource = dataSource

  }
}
```

Comment: can you paste here TableDataSource class please?

Answer (score 7):

Extending the accepted answer by "ayalcinkaya", which explains the **how** but not the **why**:

Most probably what is happening is that your TableDataSource is being deallocated as [tableview.dataSource is a weak reference](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614955-datasource), that is why creating a property solves the problem, as it creates a strong reference and avoids the dataSource delegate being deallocated.

Answer (score 6):

I used the below code, for more generic approach, as a try..

```
import UIKit

class CustomDataSource<ItemsType, CellType:UITableViewCell>: NSObject, UITableViewDataSource {

    typealias ConfigureCellClosure = (_ item: ItemsType, _ cell: CellType) -> Void
    private var items: [ItemsType]
    private let identifier: String
    private var configureCellClosure: ConfigureCellClosure


    init(withData items: [ItemsType], andId identifier: String, withConfigBlock config:@escaping ConfigureCellClosure) {

        self.identifier = identifier
        self.items      = items
        self.configureCellClosure = config
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return items.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: self.identifier, for: indexPath) as! CellType
        configureCellClosure(items[indexPath.row], cell)
        return cell
    }

    func item(at indexpath: IndexPath) -> ItemsType {

        return items[indexpath.row]
    }

}
```

In view controller

```
   var dataSource: CustomDataSource<CellObject, CustomTableViewCell>?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

         dataSource = CustomDataSource<CellObject, CustomTableViewCell>(withData: customDataStore.customData(), andId: CustomTableViewCell.defaultReuseIdentifier) { (cellObject, cell) in
            cell.configureCell(with: cellObject)
        }
        customTableView.dataSource = dataSource

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

Used this approach in my small project [WorldCountriesSwift](https://github.com/anoop4real/WorldCountriesSwift)

Comment: I placed the DataSource to separate file but don't know how to "listen to the click event & send clicked item to DetailViewController".

```class PicturesDataSource: NSObject, UITableViewDataSource{

}```

inside PicturesDataSource "storyboard" & "navigationController" are not available & therefore ```if let detailViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PictureDetailView") as? PictureDetailViewController &  navigationController?.pushViewController(detailViewController, animated: true)``` not working.

Comment: Try adding the dataSource?.item(at: indexPath) in the didselectrow method of viewcontroller and then try to present the details pictureVC.present(PictureDetailViewController.....)